# build a bijection h : R\Q → R

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I needed to find cardinality of irrationals. I have provedthat R\Q is uncountable. Now I need to build a bijection h : R\Q → R . How to do this?

Comment: "I have provedthat R\Q is uncountable." -- Aren't you done? Or did you want an explicit bijection?

Comment: If you could easily build a bijection from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$, then you wouldn't need to show that $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ was uncountable.

Comment: But uncountability doesn't assure cardinality same as that of real numbers

Answer (score 0):

Can you find a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$ to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$? What about $\mathbb{Q}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$ to $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Z}$? Last hint: $a+b\sqrt{2}$.